# PSpice/Schematics (Vers. 9.2) does not start in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

Until yesterday I have worked with PSpice (Schematics), vers. 9.2, without any problems (Windows XP - 32bit).

However, suddenly the program does not start anymore. I am sure that I have not installed anything new on the computer.

Then I`ve tried the safe mode of windows and - yes - in this mode the program worked correctly. What could be the reason? 
Of course, I have tried to delete/reinstall the program (CD-ROM).

This procedure also was possible in Windows safe mode only (no reaction in normal mode after clicking "install.exe").
Any help or tip is appreciated. 
Thank you

LvW

Answer (score 0):

I know that this does not qualify as a full answer, but a general advice is: when the program crashes on start without any error message, the first thing to do is to start it from command prompt, because it might be outputting some error messages to `stdout` before terminating.

So... open you command prompt, `cd` to the directory where the executable of your program is located and launch it from there. Look for output. This might give you some hints on what exactly went wrong.

It is very hard to give any advice with so little information provided on the issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. However - it idn´t work. No response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Terminate all instances of Pspice
3. Terminate any instances of LMTools / License Manager that are running
4. Open LMTools
5. Go to Start/Stop/Reread tab
6. Stop Server
7. Reread License files
8. Start Server
9. Launch Pspice

[image]

Comment: Than you very much for your detailed answer. However - on my computer tere is not such a program LMTools. Is there any similar tool?

Comment: Well, It usually gets installed along with Pspice.  You can find it in Pspice program group in start menu. If you don't have it then this solution will most likely not help you.